# How to update to kernel 3.8 rc7 Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

How do I update my kernel to 3.8 RC7 on Ubuntu 12.10? I need step by step instructions. I did a Google search but only found instructions on rc5 and below.

Answer (score 10):

Instructions for installing a new "mainline" kernel aren't specific for any version. Just install the packages.

1. Go to the download page for [Ubuntu mainline kernel packages](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=M;O=D).
2. Select the kernel version - e.g. [`v3.8-rc7-raring`](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-rc7-raring/)
3. Download the packages fit for your architecture. For 64 bit this is all `amd64` marked, for 32-bit this is `i386`. Also pick the architecture-independent packages marked with `all`. So:

   - 64-bit: [1](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-rc7-raring/linux-headers-3.8.0-030800rc7-generic_3.8.0-030800rc7.201302081635_amd64.deb), [2](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-rc7-raring/linux-headers-3.8.0-030800rc7_3.8.0-030800rc7.201302081635_all.deb), [3](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-rc7-raring/linux-image-3.8.0-030800rc7-generic_3.8.0-030800rc7.201302081635_amd64.deb), [4](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-rc7-raring/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-030800rc7-generic_3.8.0-030800rc7.201302081635_amd64.deb).
   - 32-bit: [1](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-rc7-raring/linux-headers-3.8.0-030800rc7-generic_3.8.0-030800rc7.201302081635_i386.deb), [2](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-rc7-raring/linux-headers-3.8.0-030800rc7_3.8.0-030800rc7.201302081635_all.deb), [3](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-rc7-raring/linux-image-3.8.0-030800rc7-generic_3.8.0-030800rc7.201302081635_i386.deb), [4](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-rc7-raring/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-030800rc7-generic_3.8.0-030800rc7.201302081635_i386.deb).
4. Install them all at once:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i /path/to/Downloads/linux-*3.8.0*.deb
   ```
5. Update your Grub bootloader (most general installations are running Grub).

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
6. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source and build, or use deb packages found in http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-rc7-raring/

3 packages should be downloaded, depending on your architecure (amd64, i386, or armhf). linux-headers-3.8.0-030800rc7_3.8.0-030800rc7.201302081635_all.deb is needed regardless of your platform. Once downloaded, open a shell prompt (xterm), cd to Downloads or directory/folder where the files were downloaded, and run 'sudo dpkg -i *.deb'. Once installed, reboot and check the kernel version via 'uname -r' from a shell prompt. Good luck and have fun.

Update: For all versions after v3.8-rc3 (including the latest v3.8.0), there is a conflict with virtualbox due to macros that were removed in include/linux/init.h. To properly build, one must either patch virtualbox source -or- use v3.8-rc3's version of the init.h header file. FYI to avoid any surprises.