# Serious lag problem with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I had 12.04 with no problems at all, but when I updated to 13.04 it takes like 5 seconds to minimize a program!

I would been very helpful with an soulution.

Comment: Can you add the hardware specs to the question. 13.04 requires a relatively modern graphics card to run well, otherwise, it will be slow, but then, you could Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead.

Comment: I have this same problem with **Intel GMA 3650**, on **HP Mini 210-4000** series netbook. (as above) Add detail of your hardware.

Comment: I am also having a similar issue on boot. Desktop comes up absolutely fine and then it goes "laggy" for about 30 seconds. I am using a Dell E6400 which uses Intel GMA4500M HD, other specs are 2.0Ghz dual core 4GB ram and SSD so there should be no issues, also it was working flawlessly on 12.04LTS. I would love to have the option to change to Unity "2D" which i realise was dropped as this new one is meant to be so much better and faster but am curious, had the option been there, would it have solved this issue for me.

Comment: Please add the results of `sudo lspci` and `sudo lshw`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and from my research have managed to pinpoint the issue - it seems that the GMA 3650 gpu had usable drivers for 12.04, but that there is a lack of drivers for and subsequent versions of Ubuntu including 13.04. I've personally had to stick with 12.04, although XBMC seems to run really slowly still.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug report about this issue, if anyone here could help...

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1188874

EDIT: it seems that this issue was fixed in kernel 3.10. To install this version:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ubuntued.info/kernels/kernel-3.10.0 -O kernel-3.10.0
chmod +x kernel-3.10.0
sudo sh kernel-3.10.0
```

Comment: What? Installing kernels from untrusted source? The bug report is useful though... But please link to similar Q&A like http://askubuntu.com/a/253549/88802 instead of suggesting to install from untrusted sources.